# Printar texto mais variavel

Tags: r, variáveis

Uma duvida, como que eu imprimo (`print`) uma variável `x` depois de um texto na linguagem R.

Assim como no `python` você faz.

```
print (f"seu numero é",x)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilizando o `paste`.

```
lenesson <- 10
paste("Seu número é", lenesson)
```

Output.

> [1] "Seu número é 10"

Comment: Muuito obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Eis duas opções:

```
x <- 10

cat("seu numero é", x, "\n")
#seu numero é 10 

sprintf("seu número é %g", x)
#[1] "seu número é 10"
```

Note que `cat` não põe a string entre aspas.
Veja ainda os formatos em `help("sprintf")`.

Answer (score 3):

O `R` não tem essa sintaxe da *f-string*, mas o pacote [glue](/questions/tagged/glue) disponibiliza algo semelhante. Com ele poderíamos fazer algo assim:

```
x <- 10
glue::glue("seu numero é {x}")
#> seu numero é 10
```

Ele funciona de forma que ele avalia códigos `r` dentro nas partes dentro das chaves dentro das *strings*.